# Join of 2 Tables X and Y to display Total sum() results event Table Y is empty

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I have 2 tables which I need to join and sum the qty based on a requirement. Here's the tables structure.

```
Customer
---------------------------------------------------
ID | Name        | Tel          | Sex
---------------------------------------------------
1  | John        | 123 XXXX     |  M
2  | Peter       | 456 XXXX     |  M
3  | Alice       | 789 XXXX     |  F
4  | Amy         | 147 XXXX     |  F

Transaction
---------------------------------------------------
ID | CustID | TranID | Books | Pens | Rulers
---------------------------------------------------
1  |   1    | Jan    |   1   |   1  |   0
2  |   1    | Feb    |   1   |   0  |   0
3  |   2    | Jan    |   1   |   0  |   1
4  |   2    | Jan    |   1   |   0  |   0
5  |   3    | Feb    |   0   |   1  |   1
6  |   4    | Feb    |   1   |   1  |   0
7  |   3    | Feb    |   1   |   1  |   0
8  |   4    | Feb    |   0   |   0  |   1
9  |   3    | Jan    |   1   |   0  |   0
10 |   2    | Jan    |   1   |   1  |   0

Required Results (Sex=F, TranID=Jan, Sum:Books, Pens & Rulers)
--------------------------------------------------------------
Name        | Tel         | Sex | B.TOT | P.TOT | R.TOT
--------------------------------------------------------------
Alice       | 789 XXXX    |  F  |   1   |   0   |   0
Amy         | 147 XXXX    |  F  |   0   |   0   |   0
```

I've tried with the following SQL statement and it is working as long as the Transaction Table is NOT EMPTY.

```
select 
`customer`.name,
`customer`.tel,
`customer`.sex,
sum(if(`transaction`.TranID = 'JAN',books,0)) as B.Tot,
sum(if(`transaction`.TranID = 'JAN',pens,0)) as P.Tot,
sum(if(`transaction`.TranID = 'JAN',rulers,0)) as R.tot,
from 
`customer` 
left join 
`transaction` 
on 
`customer`.id = `transaction`.custid
where
`customer`.sex = 'F'
Group by 
`customer`.id,
order by 
`customer`.name ASC
```

How do I modify the above to show the Customer List where SEX='F' even the transaction table is totally empty?

Comment: Stupid of me... just found out that I accidently updated the SEX field to NULL in another separate process. It is working now.

Comment: However since I already posted this question, may I ask if the way I do the sum() with the IF() is correct? Since the `transaction`.TranID is also a required condition. Is there a better way to rewrite this sql statement?

Comment: looks good to me if .TranID is not null

Comment: Doesn't look good to me! See normalisation.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL QUERY**

I hope this query will resolve your problem :

```
SELECT 
    c.name,
    c.tel,
    c.sex,
    IFNULL(SUM(t.books), 0) 'B.TOT',
    IFNULL(SUM(t.pens), 0) 'P.TOT',
    IFNULL(SUM(t.rulers), 0) 'R.TOT'
FROM
    customer c
        LEFT JOIN
    `transaction` t ON t.custid = c.id AND t.TranID = 'Jan'
WHERE
   c.sex = 'F'
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.name;
```